# Find files with certain prefix and replace prefix?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm guessing this is easiest to do with a bash script but I'm not very experienced.

I want to find all files with names beginning with "photo", remove "photo" from the beginning of the name, and then add "color" to the beginning of the name.  I also want to do this on a certain directory recursively.

So for example, say I have the file "photo_extra_text.png" in one of the subdirectories of the folder I run the script on.  After the script has been run, the file should be named "color_extra_text.png"

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way, if none of the pathnames have spaces or have directory names starting with `photo`:

```
for i in `find . -name 'photo*' -type f` ; do mv ${i} ${i/\/photo//color} ; done
```

Again, this is the quick and dirty method - note disclaimers in the comments.  For a more robust (but more verbose) method see the other answer.

Comment: As specified in the answer, this fails if any spaces or funny symbols appear in the file name. Moreover, this shows very bad practice (parsing the output of `find`). But worse, this fails miserably if there's a subfolder that starts with `photo`, e.g., `folder1/photo/`. I would not recommend this method.

Comment: As I pointed out, it's the easy way.  A bash neophyte may have an easier time understanding my approach than a more robust approach involving `find -exec`.

Comment: While it's important to have this disclaimer for future viewers of the question, I have to say this is the first and only time bash code from SO has worked as-is.  Normally I have tinker and figure out what some unknown parts are doing.  Sometimes it's nice to have it just work ;)

Comment: @pobrelkey The problem is that this solution will be here forever for other people having the same problem. In some sense, you're spreading bad practices: outdated backticks, parsing the output of `find` in a way that will break badly with spaces.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Disclaimer added to answer. I don't dispute that using `find -exec` is a more correct approach, but if I'm using bash interactively and know the files in question don't have funny names (perhaps because I've already run this loop with an innocuous command like `ls` and checked the output), I find myself using this approach - it's more succinct to type out, for starters.  If I were writing a script that might encounter strange input I'd be more likely to use `find -exec`. Perhaps this a difference between "spoken" (interactive) and "written" (script files) dialects of bash?

Comment: @pobrelkey Thanks for adding this disclaimer to your answer and insisting on it! At least, now, people using this method will do it at their own risk! (btw, it's not difficult to train yourself to use good practices naturally, so that you use them without even thinking `;)`). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not assuming anything about spaces or funny symbols contained within the filenames, and the word `photo` not appearing in subfolders:

```
find /path/to/photo_folder -name 'photo*.png' -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%/*}/color${1##*/photo}"' _ {} \;
```

Of course, remove the `echo` if you're happy with the command.

---

Another (simpler) possibility:

```
find /path/to/photo_folder -name 'photo*.png' -execdir bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "color${1#*/photo}"' _ {} \;
```

That's the command I originally gave and Tophep pointed that it doesn't work.

Maybe that's because of os x's `find` command. It actually works well with GNU `find`.

Comment: Ironically, this doesn't work... I'm probably doing something wrong, but still.

Comment: @Tophep it works fine with GNU `find`. Maybe OS X's `find` usage differs from GNU's `find`. If you could give more information: _it doesn't work_ is not really helpful.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I am just curious: What does the underscore stand for in your solutions?

Comment: @MartinR It's just a dummy placeholder because when bash is executed as `bash -c 'stuff'` then the positional parameters while executing `stuff` are set from position 0. Try it as: `bash -c 'echo "$0"' first_argument` and you will see echoed `first_argument`. Now, because we all like positional parameters to start from position 1, we just feed `bash -c` with a dummy param. Try it: `bash -c 'echo "$1"' 'dummy parameter' 'first_argument'` and you'll see `first_argument` echoed. It is standard practice to use `_` as a dummy parameter.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thanks, that was new to me!